# Keeping shape's appearance after removing it from parent in Kineticjs

Tags: kineticjs

My situation is, I have shape (image) whose parent is some group. The shape, group and other possible parents may have all sorts of positions and transformations on them. When I remove the shape from the group and add it to its layer, is there an easy way to apply everything to the shape again to make it look like there was no change, on screen?

What I have done is use getAbsolutePosition, to preserve the position, but I need the transformations, such as rotation to follow along too. In the documentation, I see getAbsoluteTransform, but I see nothing about applying that transform to a shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright... here is the hacked code for your problem --
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aplus1/uYbKm/3/)

So what I essentially did?
I changed a part of draw function for `Kinetic.Image` which now reads as follows: (you can download the **modified KineticJS4.6.0** from [here](http://aplus1games.com/js/kinetic-v4.6.0.js))

```
        drawFunc: function(canvas) {
        if(this.overrideTransform){
            var m2 = this.getAttr('OverrideTransform').getMatrix();
            canvas.context.setTransform(m2[0], m2[1], m2[2], m2[3], m2[4], m2[5]);
        }
        var width = this.getWidth(),
        ...
```

And then set the parameter `overrideTransform` to true along with setting attribute `OverrideTransform` that contains the absolute transform before moving from group to layer... like this

```
    document.getElementById('a2').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var yoda = yodaGroup.get('#yoda')[0];
        if (typeof yoda != 'undefined') {
            var currT = yoda.getAbsoluteTransform();
            yoda.moveTo(layer);
            yoda.overrideTransform = true;
            yoda.setAttr('OverrideTransform',currT);
        }
        layer.draw();
    });
```

And below is the complete code.

```
function loadImages(sources, callback) {
    var images = {};
    var loadedImages = 0;
    var numImages = 0;
    for (var src in sources) {
        numImages++;
    }
    for (var src in sources) {
        images[src] = new Image();
        images[src].onload = function () {
            if (++loadedImages >= numImages) {
                callback(images);
            }
        };
        images[src].src = sources[src];
    }
}

function initStage(images) {
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 578,
        height: 400
    });
    var darthVaderGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
        x: 270,
        y: 100,
        draggable: true
    });
    var yodaGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
        x: 100,
        y: 110,
        draggable: true
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
    });

    layer.add(darthVaderGroup);
    layer.add(yodaGroup);
    stage.add(layer);

    // darth vader
    var darthVaderImg = new Kinetic.Image({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        image: images.darthVader,
        width: 200,
        height: 138,
        name: 'image',
        id: 'vader'
    });

    yodaGroup.add(darthVaderImg);
    // yoda
    var yodaImg = new Kinetic.Image({
        x: 10,
        y: 10,
        image: images.yoda,
        width: 93,
        height: 104,
        name: 'image',
        id: 'yoda'
    });

    yodaGroup.add(yodaImg);
    stage.draw();

    document.getElementById('a2').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var yoda = yodaGroup.get('#yoda')[0];
        if (typeof yoda != 'undefined') {
            var currT = yoda.getAbsoluteTransform();
            yoda.moveTo(layer);
            yoda.overrideTransform = true;
            yoda.setAttr('OverrideTransform',currT);
        }
        layer.draw();
    });

    document.getElementById('c').addEventListener('click', function() {
        yodaGroup.rotateDeg(90);
        layer.draw();
    });    
}

var sources = {
    darthVader: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg',
    yoda: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg'
};
loadImages(sources, initStage);
```

I loved the challenge to get this working! And also thanks to @projeqht, I used his fiddle as the starting point

Comment: +1 for code that does what OP said they need.  But, won't this disconnect #yoda from its normal Kinetic transform commands--eg a subsequent yoda.rotate(Math.PI/8)?  I would mention that hacking a library'ss base code can be problematic to maintain...but I've done that often enough I can't really complain--he says guiltily ;)

Comment: Did you ever find a place in the Kinetic API that would let you "legally" set/reset the transformation matrix of a node—I couldn’t.  A few .getAbsoluteTransform’s plus a few matrix-multiplies plus one final element.setTransform would solve this task.   If you feel inspired to do so, I'll second a pull request you make to KineticJS on github for Eric to add a legal node.setTransformMatrix().

Comment: @markE In the hack above, I did it only for image but the one submitted to Eric was applicable to all Kinetic.Shape(). As for legal way, there is a method _setTransform() which copies matrix but unfortunately, it is not considered while drawing the shape. Coz my first attempt was to invert the current (after move) transform and multiply with absolute transform and set here, but it didn't work for the reason mentioned.

Comment: And yes, I'll be more than happy to solve this, except I'll be going to GDC Europe so won't be able to do it before next weekend

Comment: Thanks, this solves what I asked for, but I do also need need other transforming methods to transform the image subsequently, in particular with Tween.

I tried this. The image stays in place, but then when I tween the image, involving rotation, change of position and resizing, only the resizing is done. I suppose that's to be expected. 

Anyway, a feature like that would be nice. Suppose I'll have to clip out the shape somehow and continue manipulating that perhaps.

Comment: Am afraid that current solution won't solve that but I intend to make into another submit to @Eric later this weekend which shall be addressing this. Will update for you as well!

Answer (score -2):

Are you sure you want to ***remove*** the node from the group? You might be better off just hiding it using the `.hide()` function.

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/XxZjP/) for an example.

Either way, the shape will retain it's data, appearance and transformations as long as you don't use `.destroy()`. You just have to figure out a way to access a *removed* or *hidden* node.

## If you decide to go with **hide**:

```
var yodaImg = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      image: images.yoda,
      width: 93,
      height: 104,
      name: 'image',
      id: 'yoda'
  });

document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var yoda = layer.get('#yoda')[0];
    (yoda.isVisible()) ? yoda.hide() : yoda.show();
    layer.draw();
});
```

You can simply use an **id** or **name** to reselect the node in question, and then use `.show()` to show the image again, exactly where it was before.

## If you decide to go with remove:

Stage Init:

```
var secretLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(secretLayer);
secretLayer.hide();
```

Remove (or rather, move) Image to new hidden secretLayer:

```
document.getElementById('a2').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var yoda = layer.get('#yoda')[0];
    var yoda2 = secretLayer.get('#yoda')[0];
    if (typeof yoda != 'undefined') yoda.moveTo(secretLayer);
    if (typeof yoda2 != 'undefined') yoda2.moveTo(yodaGroup);
    layer.draw();
});
```

`secretLayer` serves as a medium to remove objects from a given layer, but still give you the convenient functionality of using the `.get()` [Kinetic.Container#get](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Container.html#get)

**If you don't want to use another layer** just to remove/move objects and hide them, then you'll need to use your own data structure to access the removed nodes. Something like removing them and appending them to an array to access later when you want to call them back.

Either way, the nodes will keep their transformations, until you `destroy()` them.